# Restructure a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a **JSON** object structured like this :

```
[
    {"CodeId": 1,"Description": "DESC1","Text": "TEXT 1 GB en","CodeCountry": "GB","CodeLanguage": "en"},
    {"CodeId": 1,"Description": "DESC1","Text": "TEXT 1 BE fr","CodeCountry": "BE","CodeLanguage": "fr"},
    {"CodeId": 1,"Description": "DESC1","Text": "TEXT 1 BE nl","CodeCountry": "BE","CodeLanguage": "nl"},
    {"CodeId": 2,"Description": "DESC2","Text": "TEXT 2 DE de","CodeCountry": "DE","CodeLanguage": "de"},
    {"CodeId": 2,"Description": "DESC2","Text": "TEXT 2 GB en","CodeCountry": "GB","CodeLanguage": "en"},
    {"CodeId": 2,"Description": "DESC2","Text": "TEXT 2 BE nl","CodeCountry": "BE","CodeLanguage": "nl"}
]
```

and I want to restructure it like that :

```
[
    {
        "CodeId": 1,
        "Description": "DESC1",
        "languages":
        [
            {"Text": "TEXT 1 GB en","CodeCountry": "GB","CodeLanguage": "en"},
            {"Text": "TEXT 1 BE fr","CodeCountry": "BE","CodeLanguage": "fr"},
            {"Text": "TEXT 1 BE nl","CodeCountry": "BE","CodeLanguage": "nl"},
        ]
    },
    {
        "CodeId": 2,
        "Description": "DESC2",
        "languages":
        [
            {"Text": "TEXT 2 DE de","CodeCountry": "DE","CodeLanguage": "de"},
            {"Text": "TEXT 2 GB en","CodeCountry": "GB","CodeLanguage": "en"},
            {"Text": "TEXT 2 BE nl","CodeCountry": "BE","CodeLanguage": "nl"},
        ]
    },

]
```

Is there someone who could help ?

In fact I want to populate a `table` with data from a server using `AngularJS`, I do not have access to the server but i can create a `JS` function to play with data.

I have tried filters in `AngularJS` to populate the table but I am using a pagination module and I had issues with it trying this way.

I believe that my one and only solution is to create a `JS` function to change the `JSON`, but if someone have other solutions I am here to hear !

Thanks ;)

Comment: In your case, grouping will be done on the bases of CodeId,Description?

Comment: Yes, the Description is unique for each CodeID, so grouping by CodeID @AmitSoni

Comment: @charlietfl I have made a solution like that but as I said I am using two different modules `angularUtils.directives.dirPagination` and `angular.filter`. With this solution I had a lot of issues with pagination

Comment: I just realized the pagination part of question... I don't see how nested arrays will help for pagination

Comment: I suppose the logical question is how you got the initial JSON array in the first place?

Comment: @vogomatix that is mentioned in the question

Comment: @vogomatix, from a SQL server using Entity Framework. I don't have access to this server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to do something like this you generally need to create a temporary object whose keys you can easily reference to be able to group like items.

Then once grouped you loop through temp object to get final resultant

```
var tmp ={}

data.forEach(function(item){
    // create the key for temp object that will be used for grouping
    var tempKey = item.CodeId;
    // OR if want to group by both CodeId and Description
    var tempKey = item.CodeId + item.Description;

    // create a new property if matching one doesn't exist already
    if(!tmp.hasOwnProperty(tempKey)){
        tmp[tempKey] = {
            "CodeId": item.CodeId,
            "Description": item.Description,
            "languages":[] // new nested array to push to
        };
    } 
    // at this point there will always be a tmp[tempKey].languages array to push to

    // manually create language object if you don't want the extra
    // properties already set above, otherwise use whole item object
    tmp[tempKey].languages.push(item);   

});
// map the temp object to a final results array
var results = Object.keys(tmp).map(function(key){
    return tmp[key];
});
```

The language objects will be the full objects in your data. If you don't want the extra properties within each of these you can manually create a new object before pushing to `tmp[tempKey].languages`. For simplicity I left that to you

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o4vfwp0e/)**</kbd>